# What does て-form plus が mean?

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-が

I'm reading 「傘を持たない蟻たちは」and there is a sentence that reads:「その肌の白さが際立ったのは、着ていたタンクトップと肘から手にかけてが黒かったからだった。」What conjugation is て-form plus が?

Comment: I apologize if this counts as an answer, but try not to think of this as て-form plus が, but instead as "〜から〜にかけて" plus が, with "〜から〜にかけて" meaning "from 〜 all the way to 〜" (にかけて has a similar meaning to まで here).